# Hyphens at DateTime.Parse?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
var d=DateTime.Parse("03-02-2013");
Console.Write(d.Month); //2
```

1) How does  `Dateime.parse` knows that : 
`-` is the separator ?  the `-` is not a standard separator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

2)How does it knows that the month is `2` and not `3` ?  is it by the regional settings ? ( I changed my regional settings and it wasn't changed)... I try to find a reference with MSDN but couldn't find any.

This is my DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo data :

[image]

Comment: But what does `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` as opposed to `DateTime.ParseExact` tries to do a best effort to parse your date. This means that it allows a number of different date separators including `/`, `-`, `.` and  (space). However, the sequence of the components of the date is still inferred from `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` which in your case `dd/MM/yyyy` meaning that the day comes before the month.

So with your Hebrew culture `DateTime.Parse("03-02-2013")` return February 3 2013 while calling `DateTime.Parse("03-02-2013", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` would return March 2 2013 because the invariant culture is based on the `en-US` culture which has the month before the day.

Exactly how `DateTime.Parse` behaves is a bit hard to figure out so **the following information may not be entirely accurate**. I believe that `DateTime.Parse` will try to look for various formats which may include `D`, `d`, `y`, `T`, `t` and also the pattern defined by `DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern`. Given a `DateTimeFormatInfo` you can get all the patterns using this code:

```
new[] { 'D', 'd', 'y', 'T', 't' }
  .SelectMany(p => dateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns(p))
  .Concat(new[] { dateTimeFormatInfo.MonthDayPattern })
```

For the Hebrew culture I get the following list:

```
dddd dd MMMM yyyy 
dd MMMM yyyy 
dddd dd 'ב'MMMM yyyy 
ddd dd 'ב'MMMM yyyy 
dd 'ב'MMMM yyyy 
dd/MM/yyyy 
dd MMMM yyyy 
dd/MM/yy 
dd/MMMM/yyyy 
dd-MM-yy 
dd-MM-yyyy 
dd-MMMM-yyyy 
yyyy-MM-dd 
dd 'ב'MMMM yyyy 
dd MMM yy 
MMMM yyyy 
HH:mm:ss 
hh:mm:ss tt 
HH:mm 
hh:mm tt 
dd MMMM
```

This list includes `dd-MM-yyyy`, but again, this list may not be entirely accurate.

Comment: CAn you please reference me to the official doc where it says that  `/, -, . and (space)` ?

Comment: @doomday1: I cannot but I tried with different separators and discovered these (but what is allowed may differ by culture). I also looked at the source code but the parser is very complex so I could not find anything specific except that there is a lot of special treatment of the Hebrew culture (which I do not think apply to your question).

Comment: On my machine, `(new CultureInfo("he-IL")).DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()[5]` gives `"dd-MM-yyyy"`, so culture _Hebrew (Israel)_ has some patterns with dashes. Not sure if that is dependent on settings and regional version of my OS, though. Your answer could still be correct in that `DateTime.Parse` might try to parse things not in the `GetAllDateTimePatterns()` list.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Based on your input I have looked some more into `DateTime.Parse` and you are probably right in that `GetAllDateTimePatterns` is involved in picking the patterns the parser will use.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) based on the current culture. Here how it is impelement in .NET;

```
public static DateTime Parse(string s)
{
  return DateTimeParse.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

I think your current culture date seperetor is `-` that's why it is working.

From [`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.currentinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets a read-only `DateTimeFormatInfo` object that formats values based
>   on the **current culture**.

**EDIT**: Okey, I'm going to more deep in this subject. As I found on internet, `DateTime.Parse` supports a lot of formats. For example;

```
Standart Time  "1/1/2000"
HTTP Header "Fri, 27 Feb 2009 03:11:21 GMT";
w3.org "2009/02/26 18:37:58";
nytimes "Thursday, February 26, 2009"
Standart Time "February 26, 2009";
ISO Standard 8601 for Dates "2002-02-10";
Windows file system Created/Modified "2/21/2009 10:35 PM";
Windows Date and Time panel "8:04:00 PM";
```

> How does it knows that the month is 2 and not 3 ?

This is all about in your culture. With `InvariantCulture` it returns `3`, in your culture it returns `2` because of standart date time format.

Comment: @doomday1 What is your culture exactly?